# reagent forms multi-select not working for list

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, reagent-forms

I was following the sample code from http://yogthos.github.io/reagent-forms-example.html and was attempting the use the multi-select option for a list.

```
(defn select-item [item]
 (go
  (reset! current-selection item)
  (let [response (<! (check-for-response))]
    (reset! current-response response)
    (reset! past-response response))))

;;batch
(defn item-list []
    [:div#items-list
     [items-list-header]
     [:ul.list-group.items {:field :multi-select :id :pick-a-few}
      (if (pos? (count @items))
         (doall (for [item @items]
              ^{:key (item "upc")}
                 [:li.list-group-item [:a {:class (set-item-class item) :on-click #(select-item item) :href "#"} 
(item "description")]]))
    [:li [:a "No Items For This Department"]])]])

(defn product-component []
  [:div
   [item-list]
   [product-response]
   ;[bind-fields item-list items]
   ;[bind-fields item-list product-response]
   ])
```

Does anyone know why I am unable to multi-select?  The logic in `select-item` will change, but I can't seem to see the multi-select in the UI

I've been messing around with `bind-fields` in my `product component` with no success.

Comment: what is the behavior you see or errors in the console?

Comment: you might post the `select-item` function as well

Comment: I did not see any errors in the console

Comment: You haven't provided how `item-list` is used. My hunch would be take a look at and make sure you understand https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-forms#binding-the-form-to-a-document. Reagent-forms components aren't used quite like other components.